# How to convert string literal into CODE, say a closure, in Rust?

Tags: rust, macros, token

As the title says, I want to convert a string literal into code. So, naturally, I come up with macro:

```rust
// main.rs
use quote::quote;
use syn::ExprClosure;

// declare a macro to expand the entire input TokenStream as a token tree.
macro_rules! foo {
    ($t:tt) => {
        $t
    };
}

fn main() {
    let code = "|x:&i32|x+1";
    // parse string literal to syn::ExprClosure type. 
    let expr = syn::parse_str::<ExprClosure>(code).unwrap();
    // return a value has a TokenStream type.
    let expr_ts = quote! {
        let slice = vec![1,2,3];
        let slice2: Vec<i32> = slice.iter()
            .map(#expr)
            .collect();
        println!("{:#?}",slice);
    };
    // call foo! to expand `expr_ts`
    foo!(expr_ts);            
}
```

which can be compiled perfectly, printing, however, nothing at all.

As far as I could understand, the reason why it prints nothing is in that `$t` in `foo!` is possibly not expanded as what I want it to. So I turned to this to try figure out if the type of `$t` went wrong:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($t:tt) => {
        println!("{:#?}", $t);
    };
}
```

which successfully printed the syntax tree of `$t`(which has a `syn::ExprClosure` type).

**Update:**

After doing some research on macro, I found that the problem was likely a misuse (or a misunderstanding) of different macro types: procedural macro vs. declarative macro.

So I refactor the code, which turns out to be a success:

```
// another_crate::lib
#[proc_macro]
pub fn foo(item : TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let code = "|x:&i32|x+1";
    let expr = syn::parse_str::<ExprClosure>(code).unwrap();
    let expr_ts = quote! {
        let slice = vec![1,2,3];
        let slice2: Vec<i32> = slice.iter()
            .map(#expr)
            .collect();
        println!("{:?}",slice2);
        
    };
    TokenStream::from(expr_ts)
}

// main.rs
use another_crate::foo;

fn main() {
    foo!();
}

// output
// [2, 3, 4]
```

> The quote! macro evaluates to an expression of type proc_macro2::TokenStream. Meanwhile Rust procedural macros are expected to return the type proc_macro::TokenStream.
>
> The difference between the two types is that proc_macro types are entirely specific to procedural macros and cannot ever exist in code outside of a procedural macro, while proc_macro2 types may exist anywhere including tests and non-macro code like main.rs and build.rs.

As noted above ([quote's doc](https://crates.io/crates/quote)), we can't use `proc_macro::TokenStream` in `main.rs`，which was exactly what I did in the first place: I used `quote!` in `main.rs` which returns a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` and expected that it would be parsed and expanded by compiler, which is not possible because the compiler accepts `TokenStream` input only if it is of `proc_macro` from `another_crate`(which is a procedural macro lib),not of `proc_macro2` from `main.rs`.

Now the question here is that if I can implement the convertion just through declarative macro? It seems that procedural macros don't accept any variable as arguments, which means you can only hardcode string literal.

Really appreciate any replies regarding my concern.

Thanks.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. The first version of your closure is a no-op, it takes a token tree and outputs that token tree, as-is, so `foo!(expr_ts)` is exactly the same as `expr_ts`, which evaluates `expr_ts` then doesn't do anything with the value.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is produce runnable code at runtime, then you need to invoke an entire compiler machinery, probably followed by updating the page you've created code into from writeable to executable since [every modern OS uses W^X by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX). If that's the idea, you should look for JIT-adjacent crates (and tutorials), as creating and loading code at runtime is what a JIT does.

Comment: Thanks, @Masklinn. Sorry for lack of better wording. So I edit and update the question to involve more details. Actually, you really get what I am trying to do by "produce runnable code at runtime". What I am focusing on is the macro feature, but what you've suggested would definitely be taken into my consideration. Thanks again.

Comment: you can't create runnable code from a declarative macro (all they can do is static *declarative* transformations). You need a procedural macro or a build.rs script (which is what tools like syn and proc_macro are designed for), and either way it'll be a compile-time feature, they can't interact with the program runtime.

Comment: Now I understand what I want is far beyond what macro can give. It has been confusing me for a while. Thanks.